# Parallax Effect without the use of background-attachment:fixed

Tags: html, css, parallax

So I am trying to create a parallax style site much like [this one.](http://www.ap-o.com/) However, whereas they use background images with a 'fixed' attachment for the effect of the image not moving, I would like to use a jquery slideshow plugin. Basically, how can I achieve the 'fixed' attachment and background position of my images if they are contained in a slider? Currently the images in the slideshow just scroll through...

I'm happy to provide code samples slash any further information needed along the way

Thanks!

Comment: Hey romboards, could you please accept ScottS's answer. I had the same problem and his solution fits perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work (just example code [use semantic id's]):

```
<div id="SlideShowContainer">Slide Show Generates into this div</div>
<div id="AllOtherContentWrapper">All other content goes here</div>
```

Then set css to:

```
#SlideShowContainer {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 0;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

#AllOtherContentWrapper {
   position: relative; /* this could be absolute depending on application*/
   z-index: 1;
}
```

This should make the container for the slide show equal to the current screen size, and fix it in place (basically acting like a fixed background). Then the rest of the site will sit on top of that slide show in the other div.

Comment: Can you please help in similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419621/make-a-div-position-fixed ??