# keep inner div fixed while scrolling outer div

Tags: css, html, background-image, css-position, parallax

I know how to achieve this effect when dealing with divs and their background-image:
I just assign my div a background-image and set its background-attachment property to fixed.

Example

```
<div class="container mask">

</div>

.container {height:400px;width:100%;}
.mask {
       position:relative;
       background-image:url(http://goo.gl/YRHZq);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-attachment:fixed;
      }
```

What if I want to achieve the same (Parallax?) effect over a google Map IFrame?

[Here my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uEWb/3/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallax Effect without the use of background-attachment:fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421908/parallax-effect-without-the-use-of-background-attachmentfixed)