# Make a div position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, parallax

I am making a very simple application where there is a need to implement parallax effect.

Things I have tried as of now,

-> Placed an image inside a div with class `parallax`.

-> Then placed an overlay div with bootstrap class `card item-card card-block` with headline, image and some text inside it.

```css
.parallax {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.item-card {
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: -24px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="parallax">
      <img style="width: 100%" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="card item-card card-block">
       <h1 class="card-title text-center">Some big text here as headline</h1>
      <div class="card-body">
        <img  style="width: 100%" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7357/startup-photos.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
  </div>
        <h5 class="item-card-title mt-3 mb-3">Sierra Web Development • Owner</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Tried applying `position:fixed` to `parallax` div but that doesn't help.

The image div needs to be position fixed and then the next div card needs to scroll over it.

Changing the given image to background image makes entire div as **not** a responsive one.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```css
.parallax {
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 0;

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.item-card {
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: -24px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="parallax">
  </div>
  <div class="card item-card card-block">
       <h1 class="card-title text-center">Some big text here as headline</h1>
      <div class="card-body">
        <img  style="width: 100%" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7357/startup-photos.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
  </div>
        <h5 class="item-card-title mt-3 mb-3">Sierra Web Development • Owner</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help.. But can you give solution without using background image which I have mentioned in question is misbehaves in responsive view..